# set constraints in XCode5

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, interface-builder, constraints

I have two labels in my interface builder. Can I set the height of one label to be half of the height of the other label by only using the constraints in interface builder? or do I have to do that with code?

Comment: Why are you not using Xcode 6?

Comment: But in general the answer is yes you can do it with interface builder, you set its height to be equal to the hieght of the label, and set the ratio to 0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the label to be a 0.5 height ratio of the other label like so:

[image]

To add the constraint, control drag from one label to the other label. Then select equal heights. Then open the constraints tab (ruler icon), and double click on the constraint you just added.

From there set the multiplier to 0.5

Comment: hi thanks for the answer! is that xcode6 you are using?

Comment: 6.1 Yes, you should upgrade as soon as you can!